# which one is best and easy way to add multiple classNames to nextjs elements?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I need to know all methods , with package and without packages too.  And the Explain why its better than Other all methods

Answer (score 1):

In Next.js, you can add multiple class names to an element by simply separating them with a space. This is the same as in regular HTML and CSS.

```
<div className="class1 class2">Content goes here</div>
```

If you have multiple classes that you want to add to an element, you can use a template string to concatenate them together. This can be useful if you want to conditionally add or remove classes based on certain conditions.

```
const isHighlighted = true;
const isDisabled = false;

<div className={`button ${isHighlighted ? 'highlighted' : ''} ${isDisabled ? 'disabled' : ''}`}>
  Click me
</div>
```

But if you are adding external .css you can only call inside `pages/_app.js` page

```
import '../styles.css'

// This default export is required in a new `pages/_app.js` file.
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

And calling style sheets like this are not allowed in components, and they should be in modular way

**components/Button.module.css**

```
/*
You do not need to worry about .error {} colliding with any other `.css` or
`.module.css` files!
*/
.error {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

**components/Button.js**

```
import styles from './Button.module.css'

export function Button() {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      // Note how the "error" class is accessed as a property on the imported
      // `styles` object.
      className={styles.error}
    >
      Destroy
    </button>
  )
}
```

You can read more in [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support)